# create table using for next loop in word document

Tags: vb.net

```
    For i = 1 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count
        docTable = document.Tables.Add(document.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, i + 1, 6)
    Next
    docTable.Borders.Enable = True
    docTable.Rows.HeightRule = WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly
    docTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Date"
    docTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Time"
    docTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Title"
    docTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Code"
    docTable.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "Condition"
    docTable.Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "No. of copies"
    For datadate = 0 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        arr(datadate) = BooksTableDataGridView.Rows(datadate).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        docTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = arr(0)
        docTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = arr(1)
        docTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = arr(2)
        docTable.Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = arr(3)
        docTable.Cell(6, 1).Range.Text = arr(4)
        docTable.Cell(7, 1).Range.Text = arr(5)
        docTable.Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = arr(6)
        docTable.Cell(9, 1).Range.Text = arr(7)
    Next
    For dataTime = 0 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        arr(dataTime) = BooksTableDataGridView.Rows(dataTime).Cells(1).Value.ToString
        docTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = arr(0)
        docTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = arr(1)
        docTable.Cell(4, 2).Range.Text = arr(2)
        docTable.Cell(5, 2).Range.Text = arr(3)
        docTable.Cell(6, 2).Range.Text = arr(4)
        docTable.Cell(7, 2).Range.Text = arr(5)
        docTable.Cell(8, 2).Range.Text = arr(6)
        docTable.Cell(9, 2).Range.Text = arr(7)
    Next
    For dataTitle = 0 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        arr(dataTitle) = BooksTableDataGridView.Rows(dataTitle).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        docTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = arr(0)
        docTable.Cell(3, 3).Range.Text = arr(1)
        docTable.Cell(4, 3).Range.Text = arr(2)
        docTable.Cell(5, 3).Range.Text = arr(3)
        docTable.Cell(6, 3).Range.Text = arr(4)
        docTable.Cell(7, 3).Range.Text = arr(5)
        docTable.Cell(8, 3).Range.Text = arr(6)
        docTable.Cell(9, 3).Range.Text = arr(7)
    Next
    For dataCode = 0 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        arr(dataCode) = BooksTableDataGridView.Rows(dataCode).Cells(3).Value.ToString
        docTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text = arr(0)
        docTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text = arr(1)
        docTable.Cell(4, 4).Range.Text = arr(2)
        docTable.Cell(5, 4).Range.Text = arr(3)
        docTable.Cell(6, 4).Range.Text = arr(4)
        docTable.Cell(7, 4).Range.Text = arr(5)
        docTable.Cell(8, 4).Range.Text = arr(6)
        docTable.Cell(9, 4).Range.Text = arr(7)
    Next
    For dataCondition = 0 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        arr(dataCondition) = BooksTableDataGridView.Rows(dataCondition).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        docTable.Cell(2, 5).Range.Text = arr(0)
        docTable.Cell(3, 5).Range.Text = arr(1)
        docTable.Cell(4, 5).Range.Text = arr(2)
        docTable.Cell(5, 5).Range.Text = arr(3)
        docTable.Cell(6, 5).Range.Text = arr(4)
        docTable.Cell(7, 5).Range.Text = arr(5)
        docTable.Cell(8, 5).Range.Text = arr(6)
        docTable.Cell(9, 5).Range.Text = arr(7)
    Next
    For dataNumber = 0 To BooksTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        arr(dataNumber) = BooksTableDataGridView.Rows(dataNumber).Cells(5).Value.ToString
        docTable.Cell(2, 6).Range.Text = arr(0)
        docTable.Cell(3, 6).Range.Text = arr(1)
        docTable.Cell(4, 6).Range.Text = arr(2)
        docTable.Cell(5, 6).Range.Text = arr(3)
        docTable.Cell(6, 6).Range.Text = arr(4)
        docTable.Cell(7, 6).Range.Text = arr(5)
        docTable.Cell(8, 6).Range.Text = arr(6)
        docTable.Cell(9, 6).Range.Text = arr(7)
    Next
```

This code should create a table in word document with 6 columns and rows according on how many rows I have in my datagridview

But it creates multiple rows more than the number of rows I have in my datagridview

What's wrong?

Comment: This should be easy to debug. No?

Comment: Are you doing programming? Why are you using multiple for loops, you could do the same in by inner loop also, you know that it would vary with 0,1,2,3,4,5 right? then why not parent loop?

Comment: how?

sorry I'm new in programming
can you show some example